# Class Design - Base class with Generic Descendant

Tags: c#, class-design

I have the following classes

```
  class GridBase
  {
    public object DataSource { get; set; }
  }

  class GenericGrid<T> : GridBase
  {
    public new T DataSource { get; set; }
  }
```

Both GridBase and Generic Grid classes can be instantiated and one can descend from either as well.

Is this considered the correct/accepted way to implement such a hierarchy?
Or should you go the extra mile and implement it like the following

```
  class GridBase
  {
    protected object dataSource;
    public object DataSource { get { return dataSource; } set { dataSource = value; } }
  }

  class GenericGrid<T> : GridBase
  {
    public new T DataSource { get { return (T)dataSource; } set { dataSource = value; } }
  }
```

The same applies to non generic classes when a property is re-introduced in a descendant, I'm just using a generic example here.

Another case and question

```
  abstract class SomeBase
  {
    protected abstract void DoSomething();
  }

  class Child : SomeBase
  {
    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
      /* Some implementation here */
    }
  }
```

The situation here is that framework "X" declares SomeBase allowing you to define your own descendants. The classes they create (at run time) then descend from your class (Child in the this case). However, they don't call your DoSomething() method, from their implementation of DoSomething().

On their part, they can't blindly call base.Dosomething() either because the typical case is that the class they generate normally descends from SomeBase and since the method is abstract that's not valid. (Personally, I don't like this behavior in C#).

But anyway, is that good or accepted design, that is not calling base.xxx(), especially when the the "intent" seems to contradict?

**EDIT** From a framework design perspective. Is it ok/acceptable that it does this? If not how would it be designed so as to either prevent such a case or better impart their intent (in both cases).

Comment: Your second question should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second form of the generic inheritance (casting the base class' attribute) is more correct as it does not violate [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It is conceivable that an instance of the generic class is cast into base class and accessing Data through the base class points to a different property. You will need to keep both in sync in order for the derived class to be *substitutable* for the base class.

Alternatively, you can implement some sort of a strategy pattern where the base class asks for the Data property from the derived class, in order to avoid awkward downcasting. This is what I had in mind:

```
public class Base {
  private readonly object m_Data; //immutable data, as per JaredPar suggestion that base class shouldn't be able to change it

  publlic Base(object data) {
    m_Data = data;
  }


  protected virtual object GetData() {return m_Data;}

  public Object DataSource {get {return GetData();}} 
}

public class Derived<T> : Base {
  private T m_Data;

  public Derived():base(null){}
  protected override object GetData() {return m_Data;}

  protected new T Data {return m_Data;}
}
```

With regards to the second question, I am note sure I understand the question. Sound like the problem you are having is to with the framework not calling the abstract method when it generates a proxy at runtime, which is always legal in abstract classes, as the only way for that code to execute is through a derived class which **must** override the abstract method.

Comment: As regards the second case, you seem to understand it correctly. However, when the proxy is created it descends from Child and Child has an implementation of DoSomething(). So in such a situation I would expect the generated class to call base.DoSomething() at some point it it's own implementation of DoSomething(). And if that's not the case then how would you impart that via design?

Comment: I don't think you can design around the framework not calling the base class. Depending on what it is(e.g. Entity Framework) you might need to modify the templates generating the proxy classes.

Comment: the question is more about how the framework should be designed. Or how the framework could convey that better or prevent such situations using a better design (if their implementation is considered "that's fine").

Comment: @Shiv, I would argue that you should always assume the worst case that the deriving class will choose not to call your base implementation.  If there is code you must execute in order to preserve your class invariants, it shouldn't be in a virtual method.  The 'base' functionality is convenient for inheritors, as it provides an easy way to tack on 'before' and 'after' logic, but they always have the option of completely replacing the code with a different implementation.

Comment: I'm marking Igor's responses as the answer. @Dan, yea that's the part that I wish there was a better way to specify intent through design.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer something like this:

```
interface IGrid {
    object DataSource { get; }
}

interface IGrid<T> {
    T DataSource { get; }
}

public Grid : IGrid {
    public object DataSource { get; private set; }

    // details elided
}

public Grid<T> : IGrid<T> {
    public T DataSource { get; private set; }
    object IGrid.DataSource { get { return this.DataSource; } }

    // details elided
}
```

Note that I am NOT inheriting from `Grid`.

Answer (score 2):

For the `DataSource` question I prefer the following pattern

```
abstract class GridBase {
  public abstract object DataSource { get; }
}

class GenericGrid<T> : GridBase { 
  private T m_data;

  public override object DataSource { 
    get { return m_data; }
  }
  public T DataSourceTyped { 
    get { return m_data; }
    set { m_data = value; }
  }
}
```

Reasons

- Having the `GridBase.DataSource` member be writable is type unsafe.  It allows me to break the contract of `GenericGrid<T>` by setting the value to a `non-T` instance
- This is more of a matter of opinion but I dislike the use of `new` because it often confuses users.  I prefer the suffix ~Type" for this scenario
- This only requires the data be stored once
- Doesn't require any unsafe casting.

**EDIT** OP corrected that `GridBase` and `GenericGrid` are both usable types

In that case I would say you need to reconsider your design a bit.  Having them both as usable types opens you up to very easy to expose type errors.

```
GenericGrid<int> grid = new GenericGrid<int>();
GridBase baseGrid = grid;
baseGrid.DataSource = "bad";
Console.Write(grid.DataSource); // Error!!!
```

The design will be a lot more reliable if separate the storage from the access of the values in a manner like my original sample.  You could extend it further with the following code to have a usable non-generic container

```
class Grid : GridBase { 
  private objecm m_data;
  public override object DataSource {
    get { return m_data; }
  }
  public object DataSourceTyped {
    get { return m_data; }
    set { m_data = value; }
  }

}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that both GridBase and GenericGrid are usable classes, that is you can instantiate both. I'll modify my question

Comment: I'd go one step further and suggest that GridBase be generic, as well.  This would avoid both the `new` keyword, and the need for a second `~Typed` property.

Comment: @James B that would prevent the storage of the abstract concept of `GridBase`. For example, imagine I wanted to store a bunch of `GridBase` values and print them out later. With `GridBase` being generic there is no way to do this for every possible `GridBase<T>` instance.